# Blank fields for form, `initialValues` not taken into account

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-bootstrap

I am using latest redux-form (v6). I am trying to get the form initialized with values from state, so I did this, according to the documentation:

```
myForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'xxx'
})(myForm);

myForm = connect(state => ({
    initialValues: {
      ...state.taskForm.taskData.parameters
    }
  })
)(myForm);
```

Then, I carefully added my `Field` components in the `render()` method of `myForm`, I use a custom `InputField` stateless component of mine:

```
export const InputField = ({propName, label}) => (
   <Field name={propName}
          component={ (prop) => <FormGroup>
              <Col xs={4} componentClass={ControlLabel}>{label}</Col>
              <Col xs={8}>
                <FormControl {...prop} />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          }
    />
);
```

(I am using `react-bootstrap` for UI)

Of course I triple-checked that `name`s for `Field`s are the right ones, from `initialValues`.

However, the form is displayed with blank fields instead of initial values.

I can see with the debugger that INITIALIZE action `.payload` contains my fields with the right initial values.

I think the problem is the following: *INITIALIZE* action is dispatched **before** *REGISTER_FIELD*. Or at least, once *REGISTER_FIELD* is dispatched, it doesn't take the initial value although the field name is properly set... But I have no idea what to do to solve the problem. And
maybe it's due to something else...

As I am desperate I tried `reinitializeState: true` but it doesn't change anything.

**EDIT:** it seems that in fact I am facing this issue [#1750](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1750), and the solution seems to be [#2210](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2210#issuecomment-246933578)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Field` passes properties divided into `input` and `meta` objects to its component and you should pass only the `input` properties to `FormControl` component. So use this:

```
<FormControl {...prop.input} />
```

instead of this:

```
<FormControl {...prop} />
```

Please check [redux-form docs](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/) for more details.